# How to highlight data from list using searchbox in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a searchbox and a div list populated by data from the database in my project. The idea is when I type something on searchbox the compatible result will be highlighted/selected on the div list. Can it be possible using ajax or jquery in codeigniter? Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: Give us a jsfiddle of a page please. We can help you beter if we know the way the page is structured.

Comment: @NicolasHenrard Hi. Sorry. Here is my http://jsfiddle.net/vEACM/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what ou want.

**JsFiddle:** **http://jsfiddle.net/vEACM/1/**

**HTML:** add a `search-field` class to your input seach field.

**CSS:** 
Add this rule to your CSS sheet: `.highlight{background-color:yellow;}`

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $('.search-field').on('keyup blur change', function() {
        var text_s = $(this).val(); 

        //Clean all by remowing eventual highlight classes already added
        $("li").removeClass("highlight");

        //Only react when a text is in the field
        if (text_s.length > 0){
            $("li").each(function(){
                var li_value = $(this).text();
                if (li_value.indexOf(text_s) >= 0){
                    //If the li_value contains the text, add a class to highlight 
                    //the li element
                    $(this).addClass("highlight");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

/!\ Don't forget to load a jQuery version (version 1.8.3 used in the jsFiddle)

**Note:** if you want to highlight elements even when the case don't allow it, simply use the .toLowerCase() when the code retrieve the value for text_s and li_value.
Example:  `var text_s = $(this).val().toLowerCase();`

Comment: Wow. Thanks.Why is it when i type the whole word it is not highlighted? I have other questions too, my populated list contain many data. 300 to be exact. Can it be scroll automatically to specified data?

Comment: If you type "Apple", the code highlight the element. You have to use anchors for your need. Check this link to navigate in your document: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579643/simple-jquery-scroll-to-anchor-up-or-down-the-page

Comment: When i type letter 'A', Two words is highlighted (The Aratilis and Banana).  But when i type 'Apple' on searchbox nothing is highlighted at all.

Comment: Refer to the note section of my post: you have to call "toLowerCase()" in lines 3 and 7 to be unsensitive to case.

Comment: Oh. Ok thanks. Kind of miss that. Wow gosh. You saved me. My only problem is the 'scrolling' part. Thanks again and have a nice day!

Comment: Glad to help you. If you're in trouble with the "scrolling part", open a new ticket. It's a "best practice".

Comment: Thanks again. I can't vote up your answer I do not have enough reputation. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a suggestions list while using a searchbox, try [this jQuery Plugin](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385892/jquery-ui-autocomplete-ajax-example) question for how to implement jQuery Autocomplete with AJAX.

Comment: Yes. I've already tried jquery autocomplete but its conflicting with my ajax list. When the autocomplete is active, the ajax list is not working.