# jQuery autocomplete fetch from function not a file

Tags: php, jquery

I want to fetch the json data from function and not file.

How can i change the *autocomplete.php* to a **PHPfunction**?

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'autocomplete.php'
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="skills">Skills: </label>
    <input id="skills">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the difference ? You have the function you want into autocomplete.php ...

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385892/how-to-use-source-function-and-ajax-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete

Comment: PHP function and not a java funcation, updated question

Answer (score 0):

Add get or post parameter to your ajax, for example *action=func1* and in your php file make a switch and in the case of action is "func1" just call func1().