# autocomplete jquery depend on five first characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

How can I use the autocomplete plugin on an input field depending on the 5 first characters typed dynamically. for exemple i have typed :

```
12345
```

And I get :

```
12345 New York.
```

What i tried is :

```
 var availableTags = [
  "12345 New Yord",
  "12378 Paris",
  "45687 Barcelon"
];

  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  minLength: 5
   });
```

The problem is : 
I have to complete the available tags depending on the first 5 charachters using a function

Comment: What plugin are you using? Is that the only code you've used for it so far?

Comment: this one **https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/**

Comment: I'm afraid I don't completely understand your question. Could you perhaps clarify on exactly what the problem is that you're having?

Comment: The code I used is ok, My problem is that I don't have a 'static' availableTags. I need To complete it with a function. 
For exemple I give the function 12345 and it returns New York

Comment: Before going any further, check out [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385892/how-to-use-source-function-and-ajax-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete), in case your question has already been answered