# how to display database field name in auto complete text box using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was trying to display items of a particular field by typing the first letter of the field into an autocomplete textbox.But when I type a letter into the textbox,random letters are shown.Please Help.I am new at this.
here is my ajax code

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function showHint(str) {
if (str.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "drop1.php?search=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
</script>
</html>

<div style="font:14px arial">

    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" onKeyUp="showHint(this.value)"/>
</div>  <p id="txtHint"></p>
</body>
```

Here is the Php code

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$search=$_GET['search'];
$query=mysql_query("select * from students WHERE name LIKE '$search%' OR name='$search'");
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo $rs['name'];
}
?>
```

Comment: What are those random letters??

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. The only minor issue is, You didn't separate each value. You could use `<br/>` like below to appear suggestions in different line.

```
 echo $rs['name']."<br/>";
```

Update input field as :

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" autocomplete="off" onKeyUp="showHint(this.value)"/>
```

Comment: hello frnd  ru malayali

Comment: @RASHEEDRAMSHI Yes!! :)

Comment: your ajax code is different from my code do u have same code

Comment: @RASHEEDRAMSHI What I told you, In your posted PHP code Change `echo $rs['name'];` to `echo $rs['name']."<br/>";` That's it!

Comment: When I use this code and type a letter I get the words which I already typed before..what I need is to populate the autocomplete textbox with the names stored in the database...can u help me with that?

Comment: @RASHEEDRAMSHI Just try with the updated answer. For `input` add `autocomplete="off"` attribute to get rid of old entered values from the browser.

Comment: thanks....old entered values are gone but auto complete  box does not bring values from db

Comment: @RASHEEDRAMSHI Check DB contains data & executes without error.

Answer (score 0):

how are you?

Try read this [Stackoverflow - How to use source: function()… and AJAX in JQuery UI autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21385958/1243336).

Or try:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality
        < /title>
            < link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
                <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">
                </script>
                <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js">
                </script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
                <script>
                $(function() {

                    $("#tags").autocomplete({
                        source: function(request, response) {
                            var name = jQuery("input.suggest-user").val();
                            jQuery.get("drop1.php?search=" + name, function(data) {
                                console.log(data); // Ok, I get the data. Data looks like that:
                                test = data; // ["one@abc.de", "onf@abc.de","ong@abc.de"]
                                return test; // But what now? How do I display my data?
                            });
                        },
                        minLength: 1
                    });
                });
                </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags"> Tags:
        </label>
        <input id="tags">
    </div>
</body>
```

your php code:

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$search=$_GET['search'];
$query=mysql_query("select * from students WHERE name LIKE '$search%' OR name='$search'");
$rs = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if(is_array($rs)){
    echo json_encode(array_column($rs, 'name'));
}

?>
```