# Run two jquery with order

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with tow jquery function, I have a autocomplete search box on form and tow function in script part. I want a function fetch a list and other one autocomplete text box but can`t call fetch function at first. It run after autocomplete function all the time.Can every one help me?

1- fetch list function is:

```
$(function ()   
{
    $.ajax({
            url: 'fetch_user_list_from_user_table.php',
            data: "{}",
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data)
            {   
                user_list=data;
                 alert("list is: " + user_list);
            },
            error: function()
            {
                $('#output').html("Error");
            }
            });
});
```

2- autocomplete function

```
$(function ()
{
    var availableTags;
    availableTags =user_list;
    alert("tags are"+availableTags);
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete(
    {
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

3- html part

```
<input id="tags" type="text" name="message_receiver_title"> </input>
```

Comment: use response(data) instead of return data. It shoud work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385892/how-to-use-source-function-and-ajax-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

call the ajax function as a callback function in autocomplete.

```
$(function() {
      var availableTags;
      availableTags = user_list;
      alert("tags are" + availableTags);
      $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'fetch_user_list_from_user_table.php',
            data: "{}",
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data) {
              user_list = data;
              alert("list is: " + user_list);
            },
            error: function() {
              $('#output').html("Error");
            }
          })
        }
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want assign user_list to autocomplete source

Comment: @daremachine I can`t fix it. Could you help me more

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to run 2 separated ajax calls then you can use [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) function which provide what you need.
But @GauravAggarwal solution is better approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want assign user_list to autocomplete source