# jquery autocomplete url corrupt

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am stuck in weird situation. I am using autocomplete of jquery. I have mapped my URL with but I am getting 404.

Now when I look at the console, my URL is showing like this:

```
myProject-dashboard-svc/organization/[object%20Object]
```

While my actual URL is like `../organization/suggestion`
below is my full jquery code

```js
$(function() {
  $("#searchByText").autocomplete({
    source:function(request,response){
      $.get({
        url:"../organization/suggestion",
        dataType:"json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data:{
          q:request.term
        },
        success:function(data){
          response(data);
        }
      })
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="searchByText" hidden="true" name="searchByText" placeholder="enter name" class="autoComplete">
```

Please let me know why URL is displayed like this.
By the way, I have checked in Chrome as well as in Mozilla and I have the jquery-ui-jQuery-autocomplete and jQuery plugins.

Comment: Is `request.term` an object? If so, you need to pick the specific property of it you want to send.

Comment: in autocomplete term is object u r passing

Comment: Ok, but the AJAX request needs a string, not an object

Comment: ya it is a string format only please see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385892/how-to-use-source-function-and-ajax-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete)

Comment: That's my point. It *should* be a string, but you are sending an *object*

Comment: then what should Id do?

Comment: You don't have to pass string to jquery Ajax. You could pass string, Plain Object or Array https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should checkout signature for get https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/. 
If you want to use get you should do it like this

```
      $.get("../organization/suggestion", {"q":request.term},function(data){
      response(data);
      },"json");
```

Or you could replace $.get with $.ajax

Comment: I replaced it with ajax and it worked but I don;t understand what difference it makes?

Comment: Signature of $.ajax  function and $.get function are different. $ajax takes one Object that contains configuration, like you passed it {url:"...", "data":"...",...} and $.get receives configuration in separate parameters $.get(url, data, success function, datatype)

Answer (score 1):

Try to send the data as a string instead of a json object.
;)

```
$(function() {
  $("#searchByText").autocomplete({
    source:function(request,response){
      $.get({
        url:"../organization/suggestion",
        dataType:"json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: {"q:" + JSON.stringify(request.term) },       // Look here!
        success:function(data){
          response(data);
        }
      })
    }
  })
});
```