# Auto-complete input with url source

Tags: javascript, html, redux, autocomplete, client-server

I need to implement autocomplete in client input when its basic list exists in the server.

So I created a function in the server that accepts text and returns a filterd list and now I have to use it in the client with the url of the server's function. My client build with Html/JS with redux.

Another **[important]** thing I need is not to access the url any keydown of the input, because I have certain rules (for optimization) that I would like to check before accessing to the server. (for example : start the search only from the second letter...)

Is there a built-in autocomplete that gets a url server for its search instead of getting a static list, and I can control that it's search will not fired in any keydown?

If not, what is the best way to implement it?

Comment: With an ajax call like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385892/how-to-use-source-function-and-ajax-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete

Comment: @CrazyProg. I see this. but I don't use ajax...

Comment: Why not use ajax?