# Why is the select field triggering the AutoComplete function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field that is connected to the jQuery autocomplete function. I was trying to get a select field to also trigger the autocomplete to refine the search results.

I have things working the way I would like them to but it isn't clear to me **WHY** the select input field is triggering the `AutoComplete` function. The county field would normally be hidden until some search results were found but I've left it exposed to simplify things a little.

I understand why the `ModSearch` input field triggers the `AutoComplete` function but not why the `county` field does too (it is only referenced in the `AutoComplete` function itself). It is worth noting that the `county` field does **NOT** trigger the `AutoComplete` until at least 1 character has been entered into the `ModSearch` field.

The code below is self contained and if it saved as PHP and called from a browser it will simply echo the contents of `$_GET` after something is entered into the search field.

[JSFiddle of the HTML and JS](https://jsfiddle.net/w1djm/d1p02Lze/5/)

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['look4'])) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_GET);
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
function AutoComplete() {
    $("#ModSearch,#county").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var look4   = $("#ModSearch").val();
            var county  = $("#county").val();
            var request = $.ajax({
                    url: 'SO_Question.php',
                    data: { look4   : look4    ,
                            county  : county}  ,
                    dataType: "text",
                    cache: false
                    })
            request.done(function( response ) {
                document.getElementById('results').innerHTML     = response;
                document.getElementById("results").style.display = "block"    
            });
        },  // end of source
    });  // end of autocomplete
}  // end of the AutoComplete function
$(function() {
    $('#ModSearch').on('input',function() {
        AutoComplete();
    });
});  // end of function
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Start typing to search: <input type="search" id="ModSearch" placeholder="Start typing to search">
<section>
You may refine your search by choosing a county
<select name="county" id="county" size="1">
<option value="">-- Select County --</option>
<option value="91">ABC</option>
<option value="92">DEF</option>
<option value="93">XYZ</option>
</select>
</section>
<div id="results" style="display: none;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit to add:**

The modification to the JS that is shown below seems to be working and is understandable (at least to me). If there is further refinement possible I am all ears so to speak.

```
$(function() {

    $("#ModSearch,#county").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {

            var look4   = $("#ModSearch").val();
            var county  = $("#county").val();

            var request = $.ajax({
                    url: 'SO_Question.php',
                    data: { look4   : look4    ,
                            county  : county}  ,
                    dataType: "text",
                    cache: false
                    })

            request.done(function( response ) {

                document.getElementById('results').innerHTML     = response;
                document.getElementById("results").style.display = "block";

            });

        },  // end of source

    });  // end of autocomplete

});  // end of function
```

Comment: `$("#ModSearch,#county").autocomplete({` <= what do you mean it is only referenced in the method?

Comment: Actually your input event handler is calling AutoComplete which is reinitializing the autocomplete every time.  That's very heavy and not necessary.  You should only have to initialize once.

Comment: To your first comment, it is referenced there but until the AutoComplete function is called the `county` element doesn't trigger the autocomplete function. To your second comment, how would/should I initialize it once?

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-option If you initialize it once, you can use the option method to update the source option as you desire.  You can also give the source a function for a value, which iirc, will run any time the value changes, which could potentially perform the ajax call there.  Would have to verify that, though I'm 99% we do it like that in one of my applications.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and description @Taplar. I understand, I think, what you are saying but not at all sure how to implement it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385892/how-to-use-source-function-and-ajax-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete